# Lyapunov CLT for Bernoulli independent random variables $X_n$ such that $P(X_n=1)\to0$

Tags: probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

> Let $\{X_n:n\ge1\}$ be a sequence of independent Bernoulli random variables with 
>   $$P\{X_k=1\}=1-P\{X_k=0\}=\frac{1}{k}.$$
>   Set
>   $$S_n=\sum^{n}_{k=1}(X_k-\frac{1}{k}), \ B_n^2=\sum^{n}_{k=1}\frac{k-1}{k^2}$$
>   Show that $\frac{S_n}{B_n}$ converges in distribution to the standard normal variable $Z$ as $n$ tends to infinity.

My attempt is to use the Lyapunov CLT, therefore we need to show there exists a $\delta>0$ such that,
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{B_n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}E[|X_k-\frac{1}{k}|^{2+\delta}]=0. \ \ \ \ (1)$$

First I assume $\delta=1$ and look at the term $\sum_{k=1}^{n}E[|X_k-\frac{1}{k}|^{2+\delta}]$ we can see,
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}E[(X_k-\frac{1}{k})^{3}]\le\sum_{k=1}^{n}E[|X_k-\frac{1}{k}|^{3}]\le\sum_{k=1}^{n}E[(X_k+\frac{1}{k})^{3}]$$.
I want to show the Lyapunov CLT holds for both $\sum_{k=1}^{n}E[(X_k-\frac{1}{k})^{3}]$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{n}E[(X_k+\frac{1}{k})^{3}]$ which would imply it holds for $\sum_{k=1}^{n}E[|X_k-\frac{1}{k}|^{3}]$.

I found, 
$\sum_{k=1}^{n}E[(X_k+\frac{1}{k})^{3}]=\sum_{k=1}^{n} (\frac{1}{k}+\frac{3}{k^2}+\frac{4}{k^3})$ 
and
$\sum_{k=1}^{n}E[(X_k-\frac{1}{k})^{3}]=\sum_{k=1}^{n} (\frac{1}{k}-\frac{3}{k^2}+\frac{2}{k^3})$.

Now the problems I am having is with the $B_n^3$ term which is,
$B_n^3=(\sum^{n}_{k=1}\frac{k-1}{k^2})\sqrt{\sum^{n}_{k=1}\frac{k-1}{k^2}}$. This sum looks really ugly to me and I not sure if I can be simplified and even if I could I would still have to show (1) goes to zero.

I was also looking at the Lindeberg condition to solve it but again I have to show for any $\epsilon>0$,
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\sum^{n}_{k=1}\frac{k-1}{k^2}}\sum^{n}_{k=1}E[X^2_k1_{\{ \frac{|X_k-\frac{1}{k}|}{\sqrt{\sum^{n}_{k=1}\frac{k-1}{k^2}}}>\epsilon\}}]=0.$$
Which I dont really understand especially the indicator function part of the expected value term. Any help or corrections would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry but what exactly is preventing you to, first compute the **exact value** of each  $E(|X_k-1/k|^3)$, then estimate the sums  $\sum\limits_{k=1}^nE(|X_k-1/k|^3)$ when $n\to\infty$? Something escapes me here...

Answer (score 1):

The Lyapunov condition holds for $\delta=1$ because
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}E|X_k-k^{-1}|^{3}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{3}{k^2}+\frac{4}{k^3}-\frac{2}{k^4}\right)\le \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}+C_1
$$
and
$$
B_n^2=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k^2}\right)\ge \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}-C_2
$$

for some constants $C_1$ and $C_2$. Then (for $n\ge 3$ s.t. $\sum_{k\le n} k^{-1}>C_2$)

$$
B_n^{-3}\sum_{k=1}^{n}E|X_k-k^{-1}|^{3}\le \frac{\sum_{k\le n}k^{-1}+C_1}{\left(\sum_{k\le n}k^{-1}-C_2\right)^{3/2}}\to 0 \text{ as } n\to\infty.
$$

---

To see that the limit holds, you may use L'Hôpital's rule and the fact that $\sum_{k=1}^n k^{-1}=\psi(n+1)+\gamma$ and that $\psi(n)$ is increasing in $n$. Then

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\psi(n+1)+\gamma+C_1}{\left(\psi(n+1)+\gamma-C_2\right)^{3/2}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2}{3}\frac{\psi^1(n+1)}{\psi^1(n+1)\left(\psi(n+1)+\gamma-C_2\right)^{1/2}}=0.
$$

Comment: Sometimes one feels that too much knowledge can be a trouble... Why not simply note that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}E|X_k-k^{-1}|^{3}=\log n+O(1)$ and $B_n^2=\log n+O(1)$, and conclude directly from these? Better to summon L'Hôpital and the digamma function only when they are needed (which happens to be almost never, but this is another topic).

Answer (score 0):

This is more a comment
than an answer.

$\begin{array}\\
B_n^2
&=\sum^{n}_{k=1}\frac{k-1}{k^2}\\
&=\sum^{n}_{k=1}\frac{k}{k^2}-\sum^{n}_{k=1}\frac{1}{k^2}\\
&=\sum^{n}_{k=1}\frac{1}{k}-\sum^{n}_{k=1}\frac{1}{k^2}\\
&=\ln(n)+\gamma-\zeta(2)+O(\frac1{n})\\
&=\ln(n)+C+O(\frac1{n})
\qquad\text{where }C = \gamma-\zeta(2)\\
\text{so that}\\
B_n
&=\sqrt{\ln(n)}\sqrt{1+\frac{C}{\ln(n)}+O(\frac1{n \ln(n)}}\\
&=\sqrt{\ln(n)}(1+\frac{C}{2\ln(n)}+O(\frac1{\ln^2(n)})\\
&=\sqrt{\ln(n)}+\frac{C}{2\sqrt{\ln(n)}}+O(\frac1{\ln^{3/2}(n)})
\end{array}
$